# Linking multiple pivot points with object constraints

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

This seems quite simple but I just can't work it out. I essentially need to make the image attached function as a single object, so that if I grab either end and move or rotate it the entire structure moves whilst pivoting in the appropriate places (the small circles). I'm thinking that maybe empties are required but I just can't get them to link to each other correctly using object constraints.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

[image: blender pivots working together as one]

Comment: Maybe parenting it to a 3-segment armature could work?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid armatures if possible. It seems unnecessary to use bones and rigging for such a simple setup. Or maybe I'm wrong — maybe it's only possible with armatures? But then I'd also imagine that I'd need to use inverse kinematics on the bones which seems over-complicated for this scenario. Would anyone know the simplest way to rig my example with just a basic armature? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use armature. There is no simpler way. Empties are more complex and I don't think they'll allow you to grab a child object to move the whole thing.